# how to stop javascript function after running once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can someone please show me how i can stop this javascript function after it has ran once?
At the moment it just repeats again and again and i only want it to run the once.

I'm still learning javascript, so sorry if its not great.

thanks

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".search_prompt").hide();

    $("#text").focusin(function() {
        $(".search_prompt").show();
    }).focusout(function () {
        $(".search_prompt").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".search_prompt").hide();

    $("#text").one('focusin', function() {
        $(".search_prompt").show();
    }).one('focusout', function () {
        $(".search_prompt").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the event handler once it has been run:

```
$(function() {
    $(".search_prompt").hide();
    function show_search_prompt() {
        $(".search_prompt").show();
        $("#text").unbind("focusin", show_search_prompt);
    }
    function hide_search_prompt() {
        $(".search_prompt").hide();
        $("#text").unbind("focusout", show_search_prompt);
    }
    $("#text").bind("focusin", show_search_prompt);
    $("#text").bind("focusout", hide_search_prompt);
});
```

### Working example

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/JqErw/

---

## JQuery plugin

If you need this several times you could write a JQuery plugin for this:

```
$.fn.bindRunOnce = function(eventType, eventHandler) {
    this.bind(eventType, function cb() {
        $(this).unbind(eventType, cb);
        eventHandler.apply(this, arguments);
    });
};

$(function() {
    $(".search_prompt").hide();
    $("#text").bindRunOnce("focusin", function(ev) {
        $(".search_prompt").show();
    });
    $("#text").bindRunOnce("focusout", function() {
        $(".search_prompt").hide();
    });
});
```

### Live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/JqErw/1/

---

... or you could use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) as suggested by `salexch`.

How could I miss this one? :-)